# What does depth_err mean in astropy.timeseries.BoxLeastSquaresResults

Tags: python, astropy

I have a `astropy.timeseries.BoxLeastSquaresResults` object, and I want to find the uncertainty in the `depth` property for a light curve (from an exoplanet transit). There is an attribute called `depth_err`, and [the documentation](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.timeseries.BoxLeastSquaresResults.html) says:

> depth_err : array_like or Quantity
>
> The 1-sigma uncertainty on depth.

But at the peak period for my data, `depth[max] = 0.0157` but `depth_err[max] = 0.319` (`max` is the index at the peak power). I don't understand how the uncertainty could be more than 10 times larger than the value itself, and there are no units or other documentation I can find describing this attribute.

What does `depth_err` mean? What units is it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`depth_err` *is* the uncertainty on depth, but the reason the uncertainty was 10 times larger than the value itself was because I did not supply the uncertainties in the data points themselves to the `BoxLeastSquares` object.
From [the respective documentation](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.timeseries.BoxLeastSquares.html):

> `astropy.timeseries.BoxLeastSquares`(t, y, dy=None)
>
> **dy**: *float, array_like, or Quantity, optional*
>
> Error or sequence of observational errors associated with times `t`.

Without supplying `dy` here, no error is raised but the `depth_err` values are useless.

Note also that if there are any `NaN`s or `inf`s in your data or errors, the `BoxLeastSquaresResults` object won't work.

However, with clean data and the `dy`s provided, my depth errors are around a nice 1%.